# Construct sparse matrix with vectors using Petsc library

Tags: c++, c, matrix, petsc

I'm learning to use petsc in c/c++ in order to use a sparse matrix factorization function (MatICCFactor) in it. The first step I did is to read a toy matrix into petsc to create a sparse matrix and view the matrix before I do anything with it. I'm a beginner with c/c++ coding BTW.
Here is the code I use:

```
 static char help[] = "Tests Petscmat functions.\n\n";

    #include<petscmat.h>
    #include <petscsys.h>

    int main(int argc,char **args)
    {
      PetscInitialize(&argc,&args,(char*)0, help);

      Mat            *A;
      PetscInt       m = 3;
      PetscInt       n = 3;
      //to build sparse matrix(CSR)
      /*
       * 1 0 0
       * 2 0 3
       * 4 5 6
       */
      PetscInt Iv[4]={0,1,3,6};     //i vec size nrow+1
      PetscInt Jv[6]={0,0,2,0,1,2}; //j vec size nnz
      PetscScalar vv[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6}; //v vec size nnz
      PetscInt nzrv[3]={1,2,3}; // nnz per row

      PetscViewer viewer;

      //MatSeqAIJSetPreallocation(A,n,nzrv);//If nnz is given then nz is ignored
      MatCreateSeqAIJWithArrays(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, m, n, Iv,Jv,vv, A);
      MatView(A,viewer);
      PetscViewerDestroy(&viewer);

      MatDestroy(&A);
      PetscFinalize();
      return 0;
    }
```

It compiles but causes Segmentation Violation when run. I find the [MatView()](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatView.html) is the root of the segmentation fault. Could anyone help me on how to use the MatView correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the matrix when running the codes in the console, you can use either [MatView(Mat, PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_SELF)](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatView.html) for sequential matrices, or [MatView(Mat, PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD)](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatView.html) for parallel matrices.

If you want to use your own viewer context, the procedure should be like:

```
PetscViewer viewer;

char matrixOutputFile[PETSC_MAX_PATH_LEN];//output file name

PetscViewerBinaryOpen(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,matrixOutputFile,FILE_MODE_WRITE,&viewer);    

PetscViewerPushFormat(viewer,PETSC_VIEWER_ASCII_INFO_DETAIL);

MatView(A,viewer); 

PetscViewerDestroy(&viewer);
```

The above codes will store the matrix into a binary file by [PetscViewerBinaryOpen](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Viewer/PetscViewerBinaryOpen.html#PetscViewerBinaryOpen). Moreover,    [PetscViewerASCIIOpen()](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Viewer/PetscViewerASCIIOpen.html#PetscViewerASCIIOpen) can be used to store the matrix in ASCII format,   [PetscViewerDrawOpen()](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Viewer/PetscViewerDrawOpen.html#PetscViewerDrawOpen) can be used to display the matrix in an X window display, and [PetscViewerSocketOpen()](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Viewer/PetscViewerSocketOpen.html#PetscViewerSocketOpen) can output the matrix to Socket viewer.